# My R code creates plots in interactive mode, but not as a script (on Windows)

Tags: r, ggplot2

This code runs fine in interactive mode and creates the plots specified. However, the plots produced when run as a script are blank. Is there a way to code this that would work both as a script and interactively? I'm using RStudio version 0.98.1091, running on 32-bit Windows 7. This works fine as a script on Linux.

```
library(ggplot2)

genes <- data.frame(Genes=c("A","B","C","D","E"),
                    Expression=c(1,7.6,100,2,67)
                    )

png("genes_with_legend.png")
qplot(Genes,Expression,data=genes,stat="identity",geom="bar",fill=factor(Genes))
dev.off()

png("genes_without_legend.png")
ggplot(genes,aes(Genes,Expression)) + geom_bar(stat="identity",fill=seq_along(factor(genes$Genes)),legend.position="none")
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the plot to a variable, then print it:

```
library(ggplot2)

genes <- data.frame(Genes=c("A","B","C","D","E"),
                    Expression=c(1,7.6,100,2,67)
                    )

png("genes_with_legend.png")
plt = qplot(Genes,Expression,data=genes,stat="identity",geom="bar",fill=factor(Genes))
print(plt)
dev.off()

png("genes_without_legend.png")
plt = ggplot(genes,aes(Genes,Expression)) + geom_bar(stat="identity",fill=seq_along(factor(genes$Genes)),legend.position="none")
print(plt)
dev.off()
```

Values "autoprint" in interactive mode. For example, right after you type `genes` in interactive mode, the dataframe is printed to the screen. However, you don't expect it to be printed to a file without a `print` statement. Similarly, [lattice/trellis/grid graphics (including ggplots)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29543024/my-r-code-creates-plots-in-interactive-mode-but-not-as-a-script-on-windows/29543107#comment47241709_29543107) also need to be printed when not in interactive mode. Explicitly printing the plot will work for both interactive and "script" modes.

This is such a common error that it is listed in [R-FAQ 7.22](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f).

Comment: This is [R-FAQ 7.22](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f). It's not true for base plots (which aren't objects and thus aren't `print`ed,) but it is true for lattice/trellis/grid graphics (including ggplots).